# What is signtool.exe for?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I have a feeling it's the equvilent of signing jars in Java, but I'm not entirely sure if that's what it is for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s9b9yaz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

> Sign Tool is a command-line tool that
>   digitally signs files, verifies
>   signatures in files, and time-stamps
>   files.
>
> Sign Tool is automatically installed
>   with Visual Studio. To start the tool,
>   use the Visual Studio Command Prompt.
>   Sign Tool has the following general
>   syntax:
>
> `signtool [command] [options] [file_name | ...]`

Regarding the `sign` command:

> Digitally signs files. Digital
>   signatures protect files from
>   tampering, and enable users to verify
>   the signer based on a signing
>   certificate.

Comment: So when somebody else gets the signed file, they can verify that it came from whoever signed it.

Answer (score 0):

It signs files with digital signatures, so I guess you can compare it with signing jars. Here's [what MS says about it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s9b9yaz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).